Somebody know how to add the anchor plugin on CKEDITOR5?
I am trying to add anchors on CKEDITOR5, but the editor automaticaly removes de 'id' atributte when i exit the text source mode, i tried to find a anchor plugin for ckeditor5, but i don find nothing that works on django.
<p>
    <a href="#bottom">go bottom</a>
</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;
</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;
</p>
<p id="bottom"> 
    bottom
</p>


It's quite simple: I just didn’t give the research enough attention. To enable the use of 'id' attributes in CKEditor 5 with Django, you can do so by adding the following configuration to CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS on your settings.py:
CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS = {
  "extends": {
        "htmlSupport": {

            "allow": [
                {"name": "/.*/", "attributes": True, "classes": True, "styles": True}
            ]
        },
}

